# psycopg2: How to execute vacuum postgresql query in python script

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Python with psycopg2 and I'm trying to run a full VACUUM in python script. The problem is that when I try to run the VACUUM command within my code I get the following error:

**psycopg2.InternalError: VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block**

The line which am trying to execute is:

sql="vacuum full table_name;"

cur.execute(sql)

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Psycopg2 starts a new transaction for each call to .execute().

Open an autocommit connection to handle a vacuum.

Read about `autocommit` in [the documentation.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit)