# Postgresql - How to open an Autocommit Connection to handle a Vacuum Full

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to achieve the same thing as in earlier question [psycopg2: How to execute vacuum postgresql query in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206715/psycopg2-how-to-execute-vacuum-postgresql-query-in-python-script); however, the recommendation to open an autocommit connection includes a link which is broken.

The below code runs without error BUT the table is not vacuumed.

How does this need to be written to call the Vacuum Full correctly?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
from config import config
def connect():
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """
    conn = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        params = config()

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        conn.autocommit=1
        
        # create a cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        
    # execute Vacuum Full
        cur.execute('Vacuum Full netsuite_display')
       
    # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            print('Database connection closed.')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Comment: Your code is OK, though `conn.autocommit = True` would be more elegant. Anyway, the script should successfully vacuum the table.

Comment: How do you know it isn't vacuuming the table?

Comment: The link in the answer [autocommit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit) works for me. Have you looked at the Postgres log when this run to see it is working? Also you might want to query [pg_stat_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) to view recent `VACUUM` activity.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver alas, vacuum full does not update that view, only normal vacuums do.

Comment: Oops, did not take my own advice and read the docs.